# C# общая структура программы!

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я новичок.
Писал программу пару недель, сейчас обнаружил, что основной файл проекта это Program.cs, а не Form1.cs )))))

Очень много непонятно. По областям видимости, директивам using.

1. Глобальные переменные как делать?!!!
   Пишу программу онлайн бот. Массив пакетов должен быть доступен "всей программе", как сделать!!!? Механизмы.
2. Почему если using WebSocketSharp; стоит в основном файле, её нужно дублировать и в Form1.cs? (скорее вопрос мелкософту)
3. Есть ли учебник или методичка именно по структуре программы, чтобы не "хрено-код" получался, а красивая структурированная программа? 
   Типа учебник по Visual Studio?

P.S.
Сейчас читаю Рихтера и Джона Скита, всё понятно, но там нет вопроса по структуре кода.

```
"Program.cs":
namespace online_Bot
{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
// Массивы данных из интернета. По идее в основном файле нужно объявлять? MyNum - свой класс, уже описанный.
        MyNum[,] OB1 = new MyNum[2, 250000];
        MyNum[,] OB2 = new MyNum[2, 250000];
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь объявить массивы в основной части, естественно они не видны для файла Forms1.cs

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Почитайте какой-нибудь "Совершенный код"

Comment: `Есть ли учебник или методичка именно по структуре программы, чтобы не "хрено-код" получался, а красивая структурированная программа?` Книги есть, например, серия книг Мартина Фаулера или Роберта Мартина. Но вообще такой навык нарабатывается годами опыта. Нелья просто так взять и сразу написать красоту.

Comment: @tym32167  Да. Слишком общий. Хотя бы помогите организовать массив для данных, которые получаются online. Что выбрать, куда "впихнуть".

Comment: @СаакШахламджян Ничего не понятно что вы хотите

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать хорошо, то вам будет непросто, та как на любой совет вам придется бежать в гугл, так как вы без опыта и половину терминов просто не знате. Например, я бы вам советовал использовать DI / IoC контейнер, и в нем сделать сервис или репозиторий ваших данных синглтоном, что позволит их использовать как заваисимости для любого вашего класса, созданного контейнером.

Comment: не надо писать на C++ если пишешь на C#

Answer (score 1):

1. Статические поля/свойства класса.
2. Это не include как в c/c++. Это декларация что ты используешь какой то неймспейс внутри другого неймспейса.
3. Учебник - любой учебник по c# и доки майкрософт, там довольно много примеров и все хорошо расписано https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio

Массивы объяви в отдельном статическом классе примерно так

```
public static class Globals
{
public static MyNum[,] OB1 = new MyNum[2, 250000];
}
```

потом обращаться Globals.OB1[0,0]=1;

Но это плохой стиль да и вообще так не делают =) Сделайте нормальный класс, инкапсулирующий работу с этими данными, сделайте интерфейс и по этому интерфейсу вызывайте операции.